# Direct to different server files of virtual host with same ip address?

Tags: apache

As mentioned in the title, if I created a virtual host and its corresponding server files, it's known that I can access  both the server files separately by typing for instance `localhost/xxxa.php` and `example.com/xxxb.php`. However, if I want to share my web server within a local network by giving out my IP address such as `10.215.43.216/xxxb.php`, it's not accessible. It can only access the server files of localhost. How should I do the configuration or is it possible to do this in a different manner?

Comment: you can have MANY hostnames mapping to an IP, and each site can have its own file structure. But an IP can map to only one site, unless you want to start using different port numbers, e.g. 127.0.0.1:80, 127.0.0.1:81, 127.0.0.1:82, etc...

Comment: So if I create another virtual host? the people on the same network can achieve my web server using the ip address like 10.215.43.216:81 something like that? correct me if I'm wrong cz I'm still new in web language